# Float property not working

Tags: css

I'm having some issues trying to write CSS to make a box float to the right of my page.

I have a div called #right-box-uploadphoto that is the grey box on this page http://s361608839.websitehome.co.uk/salesboard/After_Login.html

The CSS is this:

```
#right-box-uploadphoto{
width: 240px;
height: 240px;
background: #e6e6e6;
border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
margin-left: 15px;
float: right;
}
```

It's somehow being pushed down. It needs to line up with #page-box2.

Is this not right?

Thanks

Comment: It's definitely floating to the right. What do you want it to do?

Comment: Seems to be floating fine for me. I'm using Chrome 30 or whatever the current version is.

Comment: It's somehow being pushed down. It needs to line up with #page-box2.

Comment: It's still not clear what you want but floating items will wrap to the next line if there is no room for them to float.  It does not look like you've allowed any space on the right for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You placed the div incorrectly on your page. Try adding your div to your mainFrame like:

```
<div id="mainFrame">
<h2>Set up your Salesboard</h2>
<p>There's only a few steps to go!</p>
<div class="line"></div> 
<div id="page-box2">
<div id="step-box-select"><span class="icon-step">1</span> Set Up Your Profile</div>
<div id="step-box-unselect"><span class="icon-step">2</span> Set Up Your Team</div>
<div id="step-box-unselect"><span class="icon-step">3</span> Add Team Member</div>
<br><br>
<form action="" method="get">


</form>
<a href="#" class="upgradebutton">Upgrade</a></div>
<div id="right-box-uploadphoto"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting "right-box-uploadphoto" div into the "mainFrame" div.

```
<div id="mainFrame">
...
<div id="page-box2"></div>
<div id="right-box-uploadphoto"></div>
</div>
```

That will do the trick!