# Float property not working (sorry I know this must be really trivial for most of you!)

Tags: html, css, css-float

So..... Thought I'd have a go at creating a website from scratch! Was off to a decent start, but am now stuck. I have obviously tried to find a solution on the net, but NOTHING seems to work.
As the title suggests I cannot get my text to wrap around my floating image properly!

This is my CSS:

```
#main h2 {
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#main p {
    padding: 0px 15px 5px 15px;
    font-family: Arial;
    line-height: 25px;  
}
#main img {
    float: right;
    margin: -140px 15px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 15px;
{
```

And the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stenbjergcamping.css"/>
        <title>Stenbjerg Campingplads</title>
    <body>
        <img src="C:\Users\Desktop\Stenbjerg Camping\images\collage.png" />
        <div id="main">
            <h2>Velkommen til Stenbjerg Camping</h2>    
            <p>Stenbjerg Camping er en campingplads beliggende i en af Danmarks smukkeste landsbyer. Med mindre end 2 kilometer til Stenbjerg Landings-plads omgivet af havet og klithederne og bare et stenkast fra de store klitplantager finder du n&aelig;ppe et mere afslappende sted at koble af.<p> <p>Stenbjerg Camping er beliggende i hjertet af Danmarks f&oslash;rste og st&oslash;rste nationalpark: Nationalpark Thy, som byder p&aring; rige muligheder for naturoplevelser og friluftsliv. Dette er ogs&aring; grundlaget hos Stenbjerg Camping, hvor fokus netop er p&aring; natur og fred og ro.</p>
            <img src="C:\Users\Desktop\Stenbjerg Camping\images\welcome.jpg" />
        </div>
    </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have been stuck for so long.

Mike

Comment: Post your HTML too please. Also, why the big negative margin on the image?

Comment: If you update you question with your HTML we can help you.

Comment: Sorry. I have edited my post now with the html.

Comment: You might try `'display: inline-block'` or `'display: block'`.

Comment: FYI, your `</head>` should be before the `<body>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Float property not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613135/float-property-not-working)

Comment: Thanks Tom. Will make that change too.

Comment: Thanks j08691 for pointing out the negative margin. Yesterday I was mainly focused on fixing the float issue. Checking my site against my iPhone just now I have realised it looks a bit rubbish so next step is to make it more responsive for all screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this **[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/R6AuM/)**

I changed your `HTML`. You have to insert the `image` between `P`

Comment: wow! That did the trick! Am now very glad I asked. Didn't expect the stackoverflow community could solve my problem after just a couple of minutes. Impressed!

Comment: Anytime! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

close braces properly

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/h3Qen/2/)

```
#main img {
    float: right;
    margin: -140px 15px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 15px;
{
```

should be

```
#main img {
    float: right;
    margin: -140px 15px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Comment: It's probably just a typo.

Comment: check it out and provide a fiddle.

Comment: Not sure how that happened when I pasted it in. It has been closed properly in my document, so this is (sadly) not the issue.